# How to add View Model to a Custom Widget?

Tags: magento2, widget, viewmodel

I am extending ProductList widget and I want to call a View Model from another module `testing\ProductFeatures\ViewModel` in my own custom template.

I have tried researching on how to use the View Model but it seems like there is no resources that tells me how can I use View Model in another module. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

> First, we define the XML to intercept a target class (type) with our
> plugin:

```
 <type name="Yireo\ExampleAssignToBlock\Block\Example">
        <plugin name="yireo_example_assign_variable_to_block" type="Yireo\ExampleAssignToBlock\Plugin\AssignVariableToBlock"/>
    </type>
```

> And next, the Plugin class adds a new variable via the original
> toHtml():

```
public function beforeToHtml(ExampleBlock $exampleBlock)
{
    $exampleBlock->assign('viewModel', $this->exampleViewModel);
    return [];
}
```

Reference :  https://www.yireo.com/blog/2020-09-07-adding-magento2-viewmodels-to-widgets

Comment: So I have to create a new plugin for this? I am still new to Magento, could you please explain more?